# Android: Start service at boot, but do not launch GUI

Tags: android, android-activity, boot, launch

I'm writing an Android app that has two major components: a service which starts up at boot time, and a GUI that I want to start only when I manually launch it via its icon, not when the device boots. I know how to start the service at boot time, but it also launches the GUI at boot time, which I don't want.

I presume that this has something to do with the settings in my manifest, but despite trying a number of things, I haven't figured out how to prevent the GUI from also starting at boot time.

I should add that I do not programmatically launch the GUI at boot time. I do reference static public variables within the GUI's activity class, but I do not make any method calls or send any intents to the GUI's activity.

Here is my manifest. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="my.package.name"
      android:versionCode="0"
      android:versionName="0.1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:allowBackup="true" >

        <!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
               I want MainActivity to only start when I
               select its icon, NOT at boot time. However,
               it always starts up at boot.
             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
               MyBootReceiver properly starts up at boot time,
               and it properly invokes MyBootService. At
               the appropriate time, MyBootService invokes
               RegisterActivity. 
             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        -->
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="my.package.name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".MyBootService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Adding broadcast receiver class:

```
package my.package.name;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent bootIntent = new Intent(context, MyBootService.class);
        bootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(bootIntent);
    }
}
```

Adding service class ...

```
package my.package.name;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MyBootService extends Service {

    private static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE    = "com.google";
    private static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_FEATURE = "service_ah";

    private Context context = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        this.display("onBind");
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        am.getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE, new String[]{GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_FEATURE},
                new AccountManagerCallback<Account[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Account[]> acclist) {
                        MyBootService parent = MyBootService.this;
                        Intent regIntent = new Intent(parent.getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                        try {
                            ArrayList<String> accountNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (Account a: acclist.getResult()) {
                                accountNameList.add(a.name);
                            }
                            regIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("accountNames", accountNameList);
                            try {
                                TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) parent.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                                String phoneNo = tmgr.getLine1Number();
                                regIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNo);
                            }
                            catch (Throwable t) {
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Throwable t) {
                            // put error message here
                        }
                        regIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        parent.startActivity(regIntent);
                    } 
                }, null);

        return (START_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.display("onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**MORE INFO**

I figured out some of what is going on. First of all, I was mistaken in saying that my MainActivity was starting. Upon more detailed debugging, I see that its **onCreate()** and **onResume()** methods were not being called. However, the app's view was showing up: a black screen with the name of the app and the default icon. I originally mistook that for an indication of a full startup.

This, of course, raises the question of why that view showed up on boot, in the first place. I have some info about this, although I'm still confused as to what is going on. I stripped down the **onCreate()** method of the RegisterActivity class that gets invoked by MyBootService. When **this.getIntent()** is called, the application's view shows up on boot. When **this.getIntent()** is commented out, the application's view does not show up on boot.

Note that this is **onCreate()** of the RegisterActivity class, ***NOT*** of MainActivity.

Do any of you know what could be causing the application's view to show up when **this.getIntent()** is called?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // If the following line is commented out, the
    // application's view does not show up on boot;
    // if the following line is not commented out,
    // the application's view shows up.

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
}
```

Comment: post your broadcast receiver code. Are you sure you are not creating an intent for that activity inside your receiver code?

Comment: What does `MyBootReceiver.onReceive()` do?

Comment: Added broadcast receiver class.

Comment: I think we are going to ask for the code of your service now... ;)  Also, I don't think `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` has any use for non-Activity

Comment: IIRC, the startup code sends me an error message if I don't set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. I'll post the service a little later. Sorry, have to take care of something.

Comment: OK. Have some time. Added my service.

Comment: "I should add that I do not programmatically launch the GUI at boot time" -- the only way one of your activities appears is because someone calls `startActivity()` for it, and at boot time the only one who should do that is you. "the startup code sends me an error message if I don't set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" -- that would be quite shocking, as nicopico is correct and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` has nothing to do with services.

Comment: Yes, you're right about FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. I was mis-remembering a different case where I sent an intent to an activity. Also, I now have more info about this issue. See in my main message above for details.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are seeing is the **preview** used by Android to make the app startup seems faster. This preview is made based on the **theme** of your activity.

Try setting a custom theme for your `RegisterActivity` which more closely looks like the final result. For example, if your activity is a dialog, create a theme extending `Theme.Dialog` or `Theme.Light.Dialog`

You can get more information on this blog post from Cyril Mottier: [Android App Launching Made Gorgeous](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/)

---

EDIT: changed to actually *answer* the question

Comment: Yes, but the RegistrationActivity is not the problem. It's the other activity, called MainActivity. Some public static variables within MainActivity are referenced within RegistrationActivity, but no methods of MainActivity are called, nor do I send any Intents to MainActivity.

Comment: "MyBootReceiver properly starts up at boot time, and it properly invokes MyBootService. At the appropriate time, MyBootService invokes RegisterActivity." His problem is the **MainActivity** starting.

Comment: Thank you, and your answer provided the key. See my "Real, Actual Answer" for an explanation of how I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

***THE REAL, ACTUAL ANSWER***

Because of the help and feedback I got here, I finally figured out my problem and solved it:

I was wrong in using an Activity in the first place (my RegisterActivity class), because I don't want the functionality that I originally put into RegisterActivity to be associated with a GUI. Due to inexperience with the Android model and lack of sufficient documentation reading, I didn't realize Activity always has a view associated with it.

Now that I know this, I refactored my app so that all the functionality formerly in RegisterActivity has been moved to MyBootService. Now, no view pops up on boot, and my app does what I want.

Thanks to all for your help and patience.